# Laravel : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) on view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, google-maps

I have a laravel program code which will execute 2 data. If the data on the query there is a "banjar" it will show the distance from the banjar center point to the destination point. else it will show the distance from other center point to the destination point.

But i have an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)" when i execute this code.

code in view like

```
<tbody>
                        @php
                            //TASIK
                            $latitude1 = -7.325374900000001;
                            $longitude1 = 108.2251681;

                            //BANJAR
                            $latitude2 = -7.3708991;
                            $longitude2 = 108.5418788;

                            $latitudersk = $data->latitude;
                            $longitudersk = $data->longitude;

                            @if( {{ $rsk_tasik }} )
                                $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude1.",".$longitude1."&destinations=".$latitudersk.",".$longitudersk."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");
                            @elseif( {{ $rsk_banjar }} )
                                $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude2.",".$longitude2."&destinations=".$latitudersk.",".$longitudersk."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");
                            @endif

                            $json = json_decode($dataJson);
                            $distance = $json->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
                        @endphp
                    @foreach($rsk as $no => $data)
                    <tr>

                        <td>{{ $no +1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data->address }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data->latitude }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data->longitude }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $distance }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
```

And in Controller i use query like this

```
$rsk = DB::select("SELECT * FROM gmaps_geocache WHERE address LIKE '%RSK%'");
        $rsk_tasik = DB::select("SELECT * FROM gmaps_geocache WHERE address LIKE '%RSK%' AND address NOT LIKE '%banjar%'");
        $rsk_banjar = DB::select("SELECT * FROM gmaps_geocache WHERE address LIKE '%RSK%' AND address LIKE '%banjar%'");
```

how to solve it and view is like this
[image]

Comment: You mixed `@php` which needs plain PHP code with blade directives. Pull out rest of blade directives from @php directive or use plain variables.

Comment: what are u mean?

Comment: `@if` is a blade directive. If you put it inside a `@php` block it has a different meaning than what you'd think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use `{{ }}` in @php and @if

```
<tbody>
                    @php
                        //TASIK
                        $latitude1 = -7.325374900000001;
                        $longitude1 = 108.2251681;

                        //BANJAR
                        $latitude2 = -7.3708991;
                        $longitude2 = 108.5418788;

                        $latitudersk = $data->latitude;
                        $longitudersk = $data->longitude;

                        if($rsk_tasik) {
                               $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude1.",".$longitude1."&destinations=".$latitudersk.",".$longitudersk."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");

                        } elseif($rsk_banjar) {
                               $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude2.",".$longitude2."&destinations=".$latitudersk.",".$longitudersk."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");
                        }

                           $json = json_decode($dataJson);
                           $distance = $json->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
                        @endphp
                @foreach($rsk as $no => $data)
                <tr>

                    <td>{{ $no +1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->latitude }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->longitude }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $distance }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

Comment: i still got an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)"

Comment: "ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file"

Comment: @MuhammadAnwari i test, it is very strange, update answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
@php
//TASIK
$latitude1 = -7.325374900000001;
$longitude1 = 108.2251681;

//BANJAR
$latitude2 = -7.3708991;
$longitude2 = 108.5418788;

$latitudersk = $data->latitude;
$longitudersk = $data->longitude;

if($rsk_tasik)
{
    $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude1.",".$longitude1."&destinations=".$latitudersk.",".$longitudersk."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");
}
else 
{
    $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude2.",".$longitude2."&destinations=".$latitudersk.",".$longitudersk."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");
}
$json = json_decode($dataJson);
$distance = $json->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
@endphp
```